# Build dict from list of tuples combining two multi index dfs and column index

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, tuples

I have two multi-index dataframes: mean and std

```
arrays = [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], ['Z', 'Y', 'X', 'W']]

mean=pd.DataFrame(data={0.0:[np.nan,2.0,3.0,4.0], 60.0: [5.0,np.nan,7.0,8.0], 120.0:[9.0,10.0,np.nan,12.0]}, 
         index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('id', 'comp')))
mean.columns.name='Times'

std=pd.DataFrame(data={0.0:[10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0], 60.0: [10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0], 120.0:[10.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]}, 
         index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('id', 'comp')))
std.columns.name='Times'
```

My task is to combine them in a dictionary with '{id:' as first level, followed by second level dictionary with '{comp:' and then for each comp a list of tuples, which combines the (time-points, mean, std). **So, the result should look like that**:

```
{'A': {
     'Z': [(60.0,5.0,10.0),
            (120.0,9.0,10.0)],
      'Y': [(0.0,2.0,10.0),
            (120.0,10.0,10.0)]
       },
  'B': {
     'X': [(0.0,3.0,10.0),
            (60.0,7.0,10.0)],
      'W': [(0.0,4.0,10.0),
            (60.0,8.0,10.0),
            (120.0,12.0,10.0)]
       }
 }
```

Additionally, when there is NaN in data, the triplets are left out, so value A,Z at time 0, A,Y at time 60 B,X at time 120.

How do I get there? I constructed already a dict of dict of list of tuples for a single line:

```
iter=0
{mean.index[iter][0]:{mean.index[iter][1]:list(zip(mean.columns, mean.iloc[iter], std.iloc[iter]))}}
>{'A': {'Z': [(0.0, 1.0, 10.0), (60.0, 5.0, 10.0), (120.0, 9.0, 10.0)]}}
```

Now, I need to extend to a dictionary with a loop over each line {inner dict) and adding the ids each {outer dict}. I started with iterrows and dic comprehension, but here I have problems, indexing with the iter ('A','Z') which i get from iterrows(), and building the whole dict, iteratively.

```
{mean.index[iter[1]]:list(zip(mean.columns, mean.loc[iter[1]], std.loc[iter[1]])) for (iter,row) in mean.iterrows()}
```

creates errors, and I would only have the inner loop

> KeyError: 'the label [Z] is not in the [index]'

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I exchanged the numbers to float in this example, because here integers were generated before which was not consistent with my real data, and which would fail in following json dump.

Comment: This is an odd format to keep... is the first column of each group the column name?

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your question ?? This example is exactly the origin df format I have my real data here. yes.

Comment: I have worked out the following code: 
`{iter[0]:{iter[1]:list(zip(mean.columns, mean.loc[iter], std.loc[iter])) 
          for (iter,row) in mean.iterrows()} 
 for (iter,row) in mean.iterrows()}`
However, this is really slow, and it does not wrap up the lines correctly, because it fully iterates over first and second row, creating wrong index level[0] and level[1] dict, which are not related each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very comprehensive way of putting up this nested dict:

```
mean_dict_items=mean.to_dict(orient='index').items()
{k[0]:{u[1]:list(zip(mean.columns, mean.loc[u], std.loc[u]))
      for u,v in mean_dict_items if (k[0],u[1]) == u} for k,l in mean_dict_items}
```

creates:

```
{'A': {'Y': [(0.0, 2.0, 10.0), (60.0, nan, 10.0), (120.0, 10.0, 10.0)],
  'Z': [(0.0, nan, 10.0), (60.0, 5.0, 10.0), (120.0, 9.0, 10.0)]},
 'B': {'W': [(0.0, 4.0, 10.0), (60.0, 8.0, 10.0), (120.0, 12.0, 10.0)],
  'X': [(0.0, 3.0, 10.0), (60.0, 7.0, 10.0), (120.0, nan, 10.0)]}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mean_as_dict = mean.to_dict(orient='index')
std_as_dict = std.to_dict(orient='index')

mean_clean_sorted = {k: sorted([(i, j) for i, j in v.items()]) for k, v in mean_as_dict.items()}
std_clean_sorted = {k: sorted([(i, j) for i, j in v.items()]) for k, v in std_as_dict.items()}

sol = {k: [j + (std_clean_sorted[k][i][1],) for i, j in enumerate(v) if not np.isnan(j[1])] for k, v in mean_clean_sorted.items()}

solution = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in sol.items():
    solution[k[0]][k[1]] = v
```

Resulting dict will be `defaultdict` object that you can change to `dict` easily:

```
solution = dict(solution)
```

Comment: Awesome, this works pretty fast. I have to study the code, now. Thanks. Just a short extension: I have columns in mean, where value is NaN. How can I leave these ones out? How to adapt your code?

Comment: @Rockbar Could you please add an example or create another question?

Comment: I modified example above. There are comps at certain time-points where mean is NaN (not given). These triplets should be left out.

Comment: @Rockbar Could you edit the expected result as well?

Comment: I did so, see above

Answer (score 1):

```
con = pd.concat([mean, std])
primary = dict()
for i in set(con.index.values):
    if i[0] not in primary.keys():
        primary[i[0]] = dict()
    primary[i[0]][i[1]] = list()
    for x in con.columns:
        primary[i[0]][i[1]].append((x, tuple(con.loc[i[0]].loc[i[1][0].values)))
```

[Here is sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo3ku.png)

Comment: Could you please check, there is something odd with indentation and the last parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: There is a "]" missing at the last .loc. Therefore, the current code is erroneous. Please correct. Besides that, there is a inner tuple, which is too much; the three numbers should be in only one triplet tupple.