# dict with list of tuples to json with json dumps fails

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have created an example with a nested dict of list of tuples here:
[Build dict from list of tuples combining two multi index dfs and column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864096/build-dict-from-list-of-tuples-combining-two-multi-index-dfs-and-column-index)

However, when I call

```
with open('output/test.json', "w") as f:
     json.dump(solution, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I get the error message "TypeError: 0 is not JSON serializable". However, number 0 does not show up as a key, only as value in a tuple in a list. Thus it should not be a string problem? So, where is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try to use the python debugger or `try except` blocks to track where and why the error was happening ?

Comment: can you show the code to build 'solution' ?

Comment: also see if you are using regular integers or numpy integers, because numpy one are not serializable

Comment: and if you need only to store this solution you can always use pickle, it works on complex objects.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please paste full (relevant parts of) code, I'm not sure to understand what you are actually trying to perform

Comment: Please follow the link, where the full example is explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suddenly wondering, why my real data json dump worked out, but not the example in the link. The solution is, that the example enforced integer values, which are apparently not serializable. So, I changed the numbers also to float in my example. Now it works fine with json dump. Thanks for your hints.